# How can i create a new dataframe with cell values based on the previous row for each column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iteration

I´m very new in python, so i need to ask this question:

I have this dataframe:

[image: data frame]

I need to know how I can obtain a new dataframe with this result:

[image: new data frame]

Starting in the second row (index 1), the formula to be applied is:
`previous row cell value *(1+actual cell value)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the cumulative product of the rows after the first using [`.cumprod()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html?msclkid=b6ef43bed09c11ec82dee1a7a2172030).  Here I take the second row onwards, add 1 to these and calculate the cumulative product.  I then multiply this by the first row.

```
(df.iloc[1:]+1).cumprod() * df.iloc[0]
```

And then concatenate the first row of your dataframe `df.head(1)` with the calculated dataframe using [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?msclkid=cc0ace53d09411ecb00be99576f5b224):

```
pd.concat([df.head(1), ((df.iloc[1:]+1).cumprod() * df.iloc[0])], ignore_index=True)
```

This can be split in to parts:

```
# calculation
df2 = (df.iloc[1:]+1).cumprod() * df.iloc[0]
# concatenate the first row of df with the calculation
pd.concat([df.head(1), df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked well for the second row (index 1), but not for all the rest. The numbers changed, but not in the way that was supposed.

Comment: Oh, is it a cumulative product?  I took them as all independent of one another (i.e. a * b, b * c,..., not a * b, a * b * c,...).  If I am wrong, I will change my answer.

Comment: I have changed the answer so that it works.